# Cannot be resolved error in java, any fixes?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

*This is the error I am getting and I cant seem to figure out how to fix it.*
I was trying to make it so that once you have finished your calculations, the program asks you if you want to perform them again.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    retry cannot be resolved
    yes cannot be resolved to a variable**

My code(don't judge, this is my first program in java):

```
package calculatorpls;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {

    public static void main(String[]Args)


    {

        do {

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the first number."+"\n");

    int no1 = num.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n"+"The number you have entered is "+no1+"."+"\n"+"\n"+"Please enter the second number now."+"\n");

    int no2 = num.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\n"+"The number you have entered is "+no2+"."+"\n"+"\n"+"Please choose what you would like to do from the following options:"+"\n"+
        "1)Addition"+"\n"+"2}Subtraction(1st Number-2nd Number)"+"\n"+"3)Subtraction(2nd Number-1st Number)"+"\n"+"4)Multiplication"+"\n"+"5)Division(1st Number divided by 2nd Number)"+"\n"+"6)Division(2nd Number divided by 1st Number)"
                + ""+"\n"+"7)Multiply by an exponent(1st Number)"+"\n"+"8)Multiply by an exponent(2nd Number)"+"\n"+"\n"+"Type any number from 1-8 to select your option."+"\n");

    //String Addition;
    //String Subtraction(1st Number-2nd Number);
    //String Subtraction(2nd Number-1st Number);    
    //String Multiplication;
    //String Division(1st Number divided by 2nd Number);
    //String Division(2nd Number divided by 1st Number);
    //String Multiply by an exponent(1st Number);
    //String Multiply by an exponent(2nd Number);

        int choice = num.nextInt();

                System.out.println("\n"+"You have chosen "+choice +"\n");


        switch (choice)
        {       
        case 1: 

            float addition = no1+no2;
            System.out.println("\n"+ addition);
            break; 

        case 2: 

            float subtraction1 = no1-no2;
            System.out.println("\n"+ subtraction1);
            break; 

        case 3: 

            float subtraction2 = no2-no1;
            System.out.println("\n"+ subtraction2);
            break; 

        case 4: 

            float multiplication = no1*no2;
            System.out.println("\n"+ multiplication);
            break;

        case 5: 

            double division1 = no1/no2;
            System.out.println("\n"+ division1);
            break;

        case 6: 

            double division2 = no2/no1;
            System.out.println("\n"+ division2);
            break; 

        case 7: 

        System.out.println("\n"+ "Please enter the power."+"\n");
            int exponent = num.nextInt();
            double exponent1 = (int) Math.pow(no1, exponent);
            System.out.println("\n"+ exponent1);
            break;

       case 8: 

           System.out.println("\n"+ "Please enter the power."+"\n");
            int exponenttwo = num.nextInt();
            double exponent2 = (int) Math.pow(no2, exponenttwo);
            System.out.println("\n"+ exponent2);
            break;

        default: 

            System.out.println("\n"+ "There isnt any such option matching your entry!"+"\n");


            break; 

        }

        System.out.println("\n"+ "Would you like to perform more calculations? Respond with yes or no."+"\n");

        String retry = num.nextLine();
         String again = "yes";

    }while(retry.equalsIgnoreCase(again));

    }

}
```

Comment: You declare  `retry` in a block, so it is not available outside that block.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you.

```
         String retry;
         String again;
     do {

         Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Please enter the first number."+"\n");

         int no1 = num.nextInt();

             System.out.println("\n"+"The number you have entered is "+no1+"."+"\n"+"\n"+"Please enter the second number now."+"\n");

         int no2 = num.nextInt();

             System.out.println("\n"+"The number you have entered is "+no2+"."+"\n"+"\n"+"Please choose what you would like to do from the following options:"+"\n"+
             "1)Addition"+"\n"+"2}Subtraction(1st Number-2nd Number)"+"\n"+"3)Subtraction(2nd Number-1st Number)"+"\n"+"4)Multiplication"+"\n"+"5)Division(1st Number divided by 2nd Number)"+"\n"+"6)Division(2nd Number divided by 1st Number)"
                     + ""+"\n"+"7)Multiply by an exponent(1st Number)"+"\n"+"8)Multiply by an exponent(2nd Number)"+"\n"+"\n"+"Type any number from 1-8 to select your option."+"\n");

         //String Addition;
         //String Subtraction(1st Number-2nd Number);
         //String Subtraction(2nd Number-1st Number);    
         //String Multiplication;
         //String Division(1st Number divided by 2nd Number);
         //String Division(2nd Number divided by 1st Number);
         //String Multiply by an exponent(1st Number);
         //String Multiply by an exponent(2nd Number);

             int choice = num.nextInt();

                     System.out.println("\n"+"You have chosen "+choice +"\n");


             switch (choice)
             {       
             case 1: 

                 float addition = no1+no2;
                 System.out.println("\n"+ addition);
                 break; 

             case 2: 

                 float subtraction1 = no1-no2;
                 System.out.println("\n"+ subtraction1);
                 break; 

             case 3: 

                 float subtraction2 = no2-no1;
                 System.out.println("\n"+ subtraction2);
                 break; 

             case 4: 

                 float multiplication = no1*no2;
                 System.out.println("\n"+ multiplication);
                 break;

             case 5: 

                 double division1 = no1/no2;
                 System.out.println("\n"+ division1);
                 break;

             case 6: 

                 double division2 = no2/no1;
                 System.out.println("\n"+ division2);
                 break; 

             case 7: 

             System.out.println("\n"+ "Please enter the power."+"\n");
                 int exponent = num.nextInt();
                 double exponent1 = (int) Math.pow(no1, exponent);
                 System.out.println("\n"+ exponent1);
                 break;

            case 8: 

                System.out.println("\n"+ "Please enter the power."+"\n");
                 int exponenttwo = num.nextInt();
                 double exponent2 = (int) Math.pow(no2, exponenttwo);
                 System.out.println("\n"+ exponent2);
                 break;

             default: 

                 System.out.println("\n"+ "There isnt any such option matching your entry!"+"\n");


                 break; 

             }

             System.out.println("\n"+ "Would you like to perform more calculations? Respond with yes or no."+"\n");

             retry = num.next();
             again = "yes";

         }while(retry.equalsIgnoreCase(again));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering just to expand on nusaK's answer.

1. **You should declare utilities like Scanner which may be used multiple times outside of for loops.**

When you put the `Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);` inside a loop, a new Scanner Object will be created every time the loop runs. Since we're always scanning from `System.in`, we can use the same object to scan for all iterations.

*Since Java manages memory by itself, it isn't much of a problem but it might be in other languages.*

```java
Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);

String again = "yes"; // you can initialize again here 
String retry=""; // always initialize in languages like Java to avoid errors.

do {
   ...
}
while((retry=num.next()).equalsIgnoreCase(again));
// u can also use this, i.e. assign and evaluate at the same time but it's harder to read.
```